# ERROR Error: mat-menu-trigger: must pass in an mat-menu instance

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a menu top of my page using mat-menu and matMenuTriggerFor, 
I found an example in material website(https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples) and tried to implement it, everything works fine buut I am getting following error.

```
ERROR Error: mat-menu-trigger: must pass in an mat-menu instance.
Example:
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu"></mat-menu>
  <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"></button>"
```

in the console.
I don't know the reason. Anyone know the solution?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: @WazzaEl I posted in the second answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue solved, so apparently it was not related to the example in material website and opposite of what Muhammed explained happened. I had few buttons before menu which had [matMenuTriggerFor]="home" aaand I didn't have any mat-menu to refer to them. 
my code was like this:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="home" >Home</button>
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="edit">Sources</button>
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="sources">Sources</button>
<!--the example from material website-->
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

and it was throwing error I mentioned above, now I changed the code and deleted unused [matMenuTriggerFor] in first three button and issue solved. the working code is :

```
<button mat-button >Home</button>
<button mat-button >Sources</button>
<button mat-button >Sources</button>
<!--the example from material website-->
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Answer (score 37):

I know it too late 
but i got same error,
and use this dynamic Menu [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-topnav-menu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
,for anyone who use angular 6 and above 
open **menuitem.component** file you need to change 
this :

```
  @ViewChild('childMenu') public childMenu;
```

to this :

```
  @ViewChild('childMenu', {static: true}) public childMenu: any;
```

make sure you make **{static: true}** cause in my case it was false and give me this error.

i hope this help

Comment: You save my day! But is it possible to explain how it works?

Comment: ViewChild is Property decorator that configures a view query,
**static** is one of its metadata properties 
we set it with True to resolve query results before change detection runs
please check this [link](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description)

Answer (score 4):

I had this error and I relized that my problem was with *ngIf.
here is my `mat-menu`

```html
 <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" *ngIf="user.userType==2">
    <button mat-menu-item><a>Profile</a></button>
    <button mat-menu-item><a>Settings</a></button>
 </mat-menu>
 <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="user.userType==2" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Hello</button>
```

that somehow made him confused, I am quite beginner to material, but I guess he was not sure what is going to happen when just **one** condition will be true...
so I changed it easily to:

```html
<div *ngIf="user.userType==2">
 <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item><a>Profile</a></button>
    <button mat-menu-item><a>Settings</a></button>
 </mat-menu>
 <button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Hello</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This proplem accure when the [matMenuTriggerFor] directive  don't have a reference (template variable) to mat-menu component for example this will throw the same error in the console

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

or you may just addd the directive like this [`matMenuTriggerFor]`

the proper solution will be like this

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammed for response, you are right but I found the issue and in my case it was reverse, I am going to explain in the next answer.